# Async /Await call gets stuck in web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await, entity-framework-core, httpclient

We have a web API application which runs on .net4.6.1. We have tried several times to figure out the root cause where it is getting deadlock, but failed. Below is the code snippet. We are hitting this API endpoint every 1 minute. It will pick 300 transaction at a time for processing from the DB. We have observed that it get stuck when there are no files to process from the DB. Not sure though. It would be helpful if someone can help us.TIA

```
 public class TaxEngineIntegratorController : ApiController
  {

    public async Task Get(int id)
    {

        try
        {

            await MainFileMethod();
           

        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            SerilogMethods.LogError(log, Ex, "Get");

        }

    }

  public async Task MainFileMethod()
    {

        List<FileTransaction> lstFTtoLock = new List<FileTransaction>();
        try
        {
            List<int> lstStatusIds = new List<int>();
            lstStatusIds.Add(objStatusManager.GetStatusIdbyName(Status.ConversionToXmlSucceded));
            lstStatusIds.Add(objStatusManager.GetStatusIdbyName(Status.Reprocess));
            //Getting the serviceURL of TRTaxEngine
            string seriviceURL = objConfigManager.GetConfigurationdbyKey(ConfigurationList.TRTaxEngineURL);
            //Getting the output path for the file to be placed after processing
            string outputfilePath = objConfigManager.GetConfigurationdbyKey(ConfigurationList.TRTaxOutputXMLFolder);
            FileMasterManager objFileMasterManager = new FileMasterManager();
            TRTaxXMLOperations objxmlresp = new TRTaxXMLOperations();

            //Getting all the files list for proccessing from the DB
            List<FileTransaction> lstFiletoProcess = await objTransManager.GetFileListforProcessingAsync(lstStatusIds, true);
            lstFTtoLock = lstFiletoProcess;

            

            if (lstFiletoProcess.Count == 0)
                return;
                


                if (lstFiletoProcess.Count > 0)
                {
                var tasks = new List<Task<string>>();
                using (HttpClient httpClnt = new HttpClient())
                {
                    httpClnt.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1);
                    

                    foreach (FileTransaction item in lstFiletoProcess)
                    {


                        TRXMLResponseModel objRespModel = new TRXMLResponseModel();
                        objRespModel.strxmlResponse = string.Empty;

                        string fullFileName = item.FilePath + item.ConvertedName;
                        objRespModel.outputFilename = outputfilePath + item.ConvertedName;

                        FileMaster fileMaster = objFileMasterManager.GetById(item.FileId);
                        //Proccessing the file and getting the output filedata                        
                        Task<string> t = objxmlresp.GetXMLResponse(seriviceURL, fullFileName, fileMaster.CountryId.GetValueOrDefault(), httpClnt, objFileOperation, objRespModel.outputFilename, item);
                        tasks.Add(t);
                        objRespModel.strxmlResponse = await t;
                        
                    }
                    var result = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

                }
               
                SerilogMethods.LogCustomException(log, "Http Client Destroyed in Tax Engine", "GetXMLResponse");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            if (lstFTtoLock != null && lstFTtoLock.Count > 0)
            {
                objTransManager.UpdateFileTransactionIsPickedtoFalse(lstFTtoLock);
            }
            throw Ex;

        }

    }
```

}

//Getting all the files list for proccessing from the DB

```
    public async Task<List<FileTransaction>> GetFileListforProcessingAsync(List<int> lstStatusList, bool IsActive)
    {
        try
        {
            List<FileTransaction> lstFTList = new List<FileTransaction>();

           
            using (SUTBACDEVContext db = new SUTBACDEVContext())
            {
                //DataTable dtFileTransactions = GetFileTransactionListAsync(lstStatusList, IsActive);
                string connectionString = db.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString;
                var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

                string query = @"[SUTGITA].[GetFileListforProcessing]";
                using (var sqlAdpt = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn))
                {
                    sqlAdpt.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    sqlAdpt.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StatusId", string.Join(",", lstStatusList.Select(n => n.ToString()).ToArray()));
                    sqlAdpt.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsActive", IsActive);
                    sqlAdpt.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 60000;
                    DataTable dtFileTransactions = new DataTable();
                    sqlAdpt.Fill(dtFileTransactions);


                    if (dtFileTransactions != null && dtFileTransactions.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        IEnumerable<long> ids = dtFileTransactions.AsEnumerable().ToList().Select(p => p["id"]).ToList().OfType<long>();

                        lstFTList = await db.FileTransaction.Include(x => x.File.Country).Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id)).OrderBy(x => x.Id).ToListAsync();
                    }                        
                }
                
            }
            return lstFTList;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }

    }


public async Task<string> GetXMLResponse(string baseUrl, string fullFileName, int countryId, HttpClient client, FileOperations objFileOperation, string outputfilePath, FileTransaction item)
    {

        try
        {
            var fileData = new StringBuilder(objFileOperation.ReadFile(fullFileName));
            using (HttpContent content = new StringContent(TransformToSOAPXml(fileData, countryId), Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml"))
            {
                using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, baseUrl))
                {
                    request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "");
                    request.Content = content;
                    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
                    {
                        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        {
                            using (Stream streamToReadFrom = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
                            {
                                using (Stream streamToWriteTo = File.Open(outputfilePath, FileMode.Create))
                                {
                                    await streamToReadFrom.CopyToAsync(streamToWriteTo);
                                }
                            }
                            var transactionEntry = new FileTransaction
                            {
                                FileId = item.FileId,
                                FilePath = outputfilePath,
                                ConvertedName = item.ConvertedName,
                                ActionedBy = Process.Process3,
                                TimeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow,
                                StatusId = objStatusManager.GetStatusIdbyName(Status.OutputXmlReceived),
                                IsActive = true,
                                CreatedBy = Others.Scheduler,
                                CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow,
                                ModifiedBy = Others.Scheduler,
                                ModifiedOn = DateTime.UtcNow
                            };

                            //Inserting the new record and Updating isActive filed of previous record in Tranasaction table(Calling updateDataonTRSuccess method of TRTaxXMLOperations class)
                            await updateDataonTRSuccessAsync(item, transactionEntry);
                            return "Success";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            SerilogMethods.LogCustomException(log, "Error occured in Tax Engine", "GetXMLResponse");
                            //Log the SOAP response when the SOAP fails with an error message
                            if (response.Content != null)
                            {
                                throw new Exception(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                            }

                            return null;

                        }

                    }
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SerilogMethods.LogError(log, ex, "GetXMLResponse");
            return null;

        }
    }
```

The following changes I have done to make it work to this specific method.
Removal of this line : objRespModel.strxmlResponse = await t;
and added configureawait(false) to this line :List lstFiletoProcess = await objTransManager.GetFileListforProcessingAsync(lstStatusIds, true).ConfigureAwait(false); Below is the working code

```
   public async Task MainFileMethod()
    {

        List<FileTransaction> lstFTtoLock = new List<FileTransaction>();
        try
        {
            List<int> lstStatusIds = new List<int>();
            lstStatusIds.Add(objStatusManager.GetStatusIdbyName(Status.ConversionToXmlSucceded));
            lstStatusIds.Add(objStatusManager.GetStatusIdbyName(Status.Reprocess));
            //Getting the serviceURL of TRTaxEngine
            string seriviceURL = objConfigManager.GetConfigurationdbyKey(ConfigurationList.TRTaxEngineURL);
            //Getting the output path for the file to be placed after processing
            string outputfilePath = objConfigManager.GetConfigurationdbyKey(ConfigurationList.TRTaxOutputXMLFolder);
            FileMasterManager objFileMasterManager = new FileMasterManager();
            TRTaxXMLOperations objxmlresp = new TRTaxXMLOperations();

            //Getting all the files list for proccessing from the DB
            List<FileTransaction> lstFiletoProcess = await objTransManager.GetFileListforProcessingAsync(lstStatusIds, true).ConfigureAwait(false);
            lstFTtoLock = lstFiletoProcess;

   
            if (lstFiletoProcess.Count == 0)
                return;
          

            if (lstFiletoProcess.Count > 0)
            {
                var tasks = new List<Task<string>>();
                using (HttpClient httpClnt = new HttpClient())
                {
                    httpClnt.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1);
                    //Getting the files for processing 
                  
                    foreach (FileTransaction item in lstFiletoProcess)
                    {
                        TRXMLResponseModel objRespModel = new TRXMLResponseModel();
                        objRespModel.strxmlResponse = string.Empty;

                        string fullFileName = item.FilePath + item.ConvertedName;
                        objRespModel.outputFilename = outputfilePath + item.ConvertedName;

                        FileMaster fileMaster = objFileMasterManager.GetById(item.FileId);
                        //Proccessing the file and getting the output filedata                        
                        Task<string> t = objxmlresp.GetXMLResponse(seriviceURL, fullFileName, fileMaster.CountryId.GetValueOrDefault(), httpClnt, objFileOperation, objRespModel.outputFilename, item, objTransManager);
                        tasks.Add(t);

                        //objRespModel.strxmlResponse = await t;
                       
                    }
                    var result = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

                }                 
            }

        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            if (lstFTtoLock != null && lstFTtoLock.Count > 0)
            {
                objTransManager.UpdateFileTransactionIsPickedtoFalse(lstFTtoLock);
            }
            throw Ex;

        }

    }
```

Comment: For .NET Framework, you should put `.ConfigureAwait(false)` each time you `await`.  It sounds to me like your code is using the wrong context.  Also `new HttpClient()` is wrong (google "you are using HttpClient wrong" )

Comment: The code is blocking itself. In the Old ASP.NET, `await` will try to get back to the request's synchronization context (somewhat like a thread). That context is blocked by `Task.WhenAll` though, so all those task will be trying to get back to something that's already blocked waiting for themj

Comment: And some of those calls make little sense. Why add `t` to the list of tasks when `await t` ensures it's *already* completed? Unless there's another `tasks.Add` in that method, there's no reason for `Tasks.WhenAll` at all

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm sorry but you are wrong. `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);` is not blocking call. More than that, the `t` is already awaited, hence `Task.WhenAll(tasks)` will return immediately.

Comment: You should really clean up this code, and break long methods into smaller methods doing *one* thing. It's very hard to see what does what now, or things that may conflict with each other. And clean up the names. That `objxml` prefix means nothing. Everything is an object, and nobody really cares that the response string is an XML. Type prefixes on properties are really bad too. What if you change your code to use WCF to call what looks to be a web service? Or use XmlSerializer to deserialize the response directly to the final type?

Comment: @Artur which means it's a useless call, and the code is so convoluted we can't tell. `await` in ASP.NET Old will block if the sync context is blocked. That's a fact. That's why `ConfigureAwait(false)` is needed. BUT making sense of this long method is really hard

Comment: What is `GetFileListforProcessingAsync` trying to do? Use both an old-style DataTable and DataAdapter *and* EF Core ? And judging by the timeout value, it's already way too slow?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `ConfigureAwait(false)` is just a workaround for real problem. The real problem is blocking on async method with `.Result` or `.Wait()`. That should be avoided. Using `ConfigureAwait(false)` blindly can bring another problems like `HttpContext.Current` set to `null`. The asker should look for blocking async methods and fix that instead of polluting the code with `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Comment: But I'm absolutely agree that this code have a lot of problems except deadlocking

Comment: @Artur yes, I know. And part of the real problem is the code itself. It looks like snippets were thrown together to get stuff to work. What's that `lock` in the data access method? To fix this, the code needs refactoring to make it readable. Although I start to suspect it would be easier to discard it completely and solve the **real problem**. If the OP wants to queue calls to a web service, this code won't do it. And use a WCF proxy instead of HttpClient

Comment: @Artur making web service calls from a queue is a long-running task, which means it needs a hosted service with a Queue<T> of messages to process, or better yet, a `Channel<T>`. Or a timed Hangfire job to process a batch of messages every N minutes.

Comment: There are still async metods we can't see (GetXMLResponse, GetFileListforProcessingAsync). The async implementations must be perfect. Do you have any .Wait() or .Result in you codebase?

Comment: I have updated the question with both GetXMLResponse, GetFileListforProcessingAsync methods included

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos GetFileListforProcessingAsync method executes the stored procedure and it will return 300 top Id for processing, then we are getting the filetransaction object for the 300 records. The DB has more than 50 lakhs records and the Stored procedure usually gives the result in 5 seconds

Comment: comment out this line : "objRespModel.strxmlResponse = await t;". it was not used.

Comment: We were able to get the logic working. Thanks for all your recommendation and time.There were 2 changes that I have done based on the recommendation and it is working as expected without any fuss. I have updated the working method as the answer in the question. The changes are 1:  List<FileTransaction> lstFiletoProcess = await objTransManager.GetFileListforProcessingAsync(lstStatusIds, true).ConfigureAwait(false); and 2: Removal of this line objRespModel.strxmlResponse = await t;

Answer (score 0):

My Recommendation:

The method "Get(int id)" is somewhat confusing. first, it takes "id" and does nothing with it. Also it return nothing so it is not a "Get" method. It is basically asking for all transactions with status "Status.ConversionToXmlSucceded" & "Status.Reprocess" and are active to be gotten and processed via the "objxmlresp.GetXMLResponse" method... You Dont Have To Await the "MainFileMethod();" in "Get(int id)" just return the task or return Ok(); and allow all the process to go on in the background. You can experiment with reducing the "sqlAdpt.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 60000;".